# Entity Framework Error Deleting Entity with Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, poco

I am having a problem deleting some entities due to a foreign key relationship. I understand the following error message and have been doing everything I can think of to delete the entities without incurring this error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_QuizUserAnswer_QuizWithQuestion". The conflict occurred in
>   database "SomeDatabase", table "dbo.QuizUserAnswer", column
>   'idQuizQuestion'. The statement has been terminated.

Here is an image of the two tables in question:

[image]

I am trying to delete **QuizWithQuestion** entities. I have made the idQuizQuestion column **nullable**. So, the foreign key is nullable on the QuizUserAnswer side.
In the mapping files, I have specified that the relationship is **optional**:

```
HasMany(t => t.QuizUserAnswers)
    .WithOptional(t => t.QuizWithQuestion)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.idQuizQuestion);

HasOptional(t => t.QuizWithQuestion)
    .WithMany(t => t.QuizUserAnswers)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.idQuizQuestion);
```

I have tried many, many snippets of code, so I will post the current state of the code in the hope that my intention is clear:

```
    public void RemoveQuestionsFromQuiz(IEnumerable<int> deletedQuestions, int quizId)
    {
        var quiz = // code which retrieves quiz

        foreach (var deletedQuestion in deletedQuestions)
        {
            var quizWithQuestion = quiz.QuizWithQuestions.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == deletedQuestion);

            if (!ReferenceEquals(null, quizWithQuestion))
            {
                db.Entry(quizWithQuestion).State = EntityState.Deleted;                    
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Another attempt looks like this:

```
public void RemoveQuestionsFromQuiz(IEnumerable<int> deletedQuestions, int quizId)
{
    var quiz = // code which retrieves quiz

    foreach (var deletedQuestion in deletedQuestions)
    {
        var quizWithQuestion = quiz.QuizWithQuestions.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == deletedQuestion);

        if (!ReferenceEquals(null, quizWithQuestion))
        {
            foreach (var quizUserAnswer in quizWithQuestion.QuizUserAnswers)
            {
                quizUserAnswer.idQuizQuestion = null; // nullable
                quizWithQuestion.QuizUserAnswers.Remove(quizUserAnswer);
                db.Entry(quizUserAnswer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            quiz.QuizWithQuestions.Remove(quizWithQuestion);

            db.Entry(quizWithQuestion).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
    }
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

How can I delete these darn entities (I'm so close to writing a stored procedure)?

Comment: The exception says the question can't be deleted because there are user answers referencing the question (not in so many words). You're deleting the quiz, the questions on the quiz, but do you plan to delete questions against the questions also (that sounds bad). Or should you be storing answers in a denormalized manner without their foreign keys?

Comment: Why are you setting the entry states? Do the entities start out detached? If they are already attached, a lot of lines seem redundant.

Comment: @Smudge202 I do want to be able to delete the QuizWithQuestion, but leave the orphaned QuizUserAnswer. By having a nullable foreign key, I should be able to do that. I don't understand why it will not permit me to do it.

Comment: @jjj I'm only concerned with deleting the entities. I don't mind if there are heaps of redunadant lines at this stage. Some of those are hail mary's. I just want the job done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you already have the question ids to delete, something like this should work:

```
// assuming db is your DbContext
var questions = db.QuizWithQuestions
                  .Where(q => deletedQuestions.Contains(q.Id))
                  .Include(q => q.QuizUserAnswers);

// assuming this is your DbSet
db.QuizWithQuestions.RemoveRange(questions);

db.SaveChanges();
```

If the `QuizUserAnswer` entities are loaded into the context (which is what include should do), Entity Framework should handle setting the foreign keys to null.

Comment: Kicking myself. I forgot to **include** that up front. Forest for the trees. I knew it would be something simple.