# Entityframework why does coupling table get duplicated values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I want to create new users in an application and assign roles to them. i have a coupling table between the user and role table. I manage to create a relationship between the tables but at the same time I am getting duplicates.

**My model:**

[image]

**Problem**:

Getting duplicates after the relationship is created. lets say I create a user with the role of "Support". The networkWebuserRoles gets the relationship BUT at the same time the NetworkWebRole gets a duplicate value.

context:

[image]

Code:

```
    var user = _dbContext.NetworkWebUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);

    user.NetworkWebRole.Add(new NetworkWebRole
    {
        RoleName = role.ToString()
    });

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

creates a relationship between the role and user but It gives me duplicates.

Result :

[image]

EDIT:

To clarify:

When I run code above this happens:

NetworkWebUserRoles gets a new connection. BUT for some reason the 
NetworkWebRole also gets a new value so I get duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re creating a new NetworkWebUserRole instead of linking to an existing record.

I’d also recommend creating a uniqueness constraint on NetworkWebUserRole to prevent roles with duplicate names at the DB level.

Example:

```
user.NetworkWebRole.Add(role);
```

This assumes that your role variable is of type `NetworkWebRole`. When you use the `Add` method of the `user.NetworkWebRole`, it will automatically create the entry in the `NetworkWebUserRole` table.  If the role doesn't exist, e.g. calling `new NetworkWebRole()`, it'll insert into the coupling table and into the `NetworkWebUserRoles` table. So by passing the existing role object (presumably being tracked by your EF context), you're good to go.

Comment: NetworkWebUserRole does not exists in my db context. In other words I have no entity to work with

Comment: This is beautifully simplistic that it is almost scary dumb in a way. I will be accepting this answer but please review my answer below just to guarantee that I did this correctly.

Comment: Thanks!  Will do.  It’ll be later today before I can look at it.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Jason Armstrong I modified my code to the following:

```
var user = _dbContext.NetworkWebUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);

// find the role that already exist in the database
var roleExisting = _dbContext.NetworkWebRole.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoleName == role.ToString());

user.NetworkWebRole.Add(roleExisting); // connect the user to an existing role
                                     // entity framework add() will connect 
                                     //it in relationship table

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Something to note for those who might be struggling with this is that you do not want to create a new role so `new Role(`)` is incorrect here. You fetch an existing role from the database and connect the user to it.

I also updated my roletable so that the rolename is unique

EDIT:

As an edit to this I figured it would be good to know how to delete the relationship aswell.

In my case :

```
    var user = _dbContext.NetworkWebUser.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(v=> v.NetworkWebRole);

    _dbContext.NetworkWebUser.RemoveRange(user);

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Found the answer to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351762/entity-framework-error-deleting-entity-with-foreign-key-relationship)